# need help understanding why I'm getting this error message in OpenCV C code...?

Tags: c++, opencv

here is the error:

```
Error no Operand "<<" matches these operands
```

the line I get error on is:

```
cout << "M = "<< endl << " " << size << endl << endl;
```

but if I use this line I get no error:

```
cout << "M = "<< endl << " " << frame << endl << endl;
```

here is the code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


using namespace std;
int main(){
CvCapture* capture =0;

capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
if(!capture){
//printf("Capture failure\n");
return -1;
}

IplImage* frame=0;
int size = 0;
cvNamedWindow("Video");


//iterate through each frames of the video
while(true){

frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
if(!frame) break;

frame=cvCloneImage(frame);

CvSize size = cvGetSize(frame);
cout << "M = "<< endl << " " << size << endl << endl;
//Clean up used images

cvReleaseImage(&frame);

//Wait 50mS
int c = cvWaitKey(10);
//If 'ESC' is pressed, break the loop
if((char)c==27 ) break;
}

cvDestroyAllWindows() ;
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

return 0;
}
//////////////////////////////////////
```

why is that....please help me get output of variable "size"
and please cite online resource for your answer so I may learn to get output of any OpenCV variable.

Comment: Why C in the title and tags ? This looks like C++ ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no CvSize stream inserter. If you want that syntax, then define one:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const CvSize& siz)
{
    os << siz.width << ',' << siz.height;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: don't really understand your answer @WhozCraig ...This is for a computer science project and I'm new to C I'd like to be able to set a variable like 
char a = #S(SIZE :WIDTH 1280 :HEIGHT 1024); and pass it to a function like this

  IplImage* imgThresh=cvCreateImage(a ,IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

but I need to know what string would satisfy the first parameter of cvCreateImage....I'd like to see the mechanism behind the Code so I can Wrap it ...

Comment: @user2735131 This simply declares a stream insertion operator (you're using them already for types like `const char *`. This allows you to have a variable of type `CvSize`, which an output stream normally doesn't understand, and send a variable of that type to the stream. So rather than doing this: `cout << siz.width << ',' << siz.height << endl` you can do this: `cout << siz << endl;`. In other words, it makes the syntax you have that currently does *not* work, work.

Comment: @user2735131 and yes, you can use this same concept for any data type you want to send to a `std::ostream` or derivations therein (like a file stream, for example). Many types (all the native types like `int`, `char`, `float`, etc..) are already part of the standard library. When you have a type that *isn't* part of the standard library, you can do this.

Comment: when I enter your function into my code directly underneath CvSize size = cvGetSize(frame);  after I changed it so it reads 

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const CvSize& size)
            {
            os << size.width << ',' << size.height;
            return os;
            }

I get Error: Expected a ";" on the first Bracket.....this is in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Don't put it *underneath*. It's a function, declare and define it like any other function. In your case I would put it before main.

Comment: I voted for @WhozCraig answer but john you really helped me too.....thanks so much both of you for taking the time to help me ....If there are other ways to vote you both up let me know and I will....a good day to you both =)

Comment: @john pls see last comment

Answer (score 1):

`CvSize` is a [structure](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/basic_structures.html)  and `size` is of type `CvSize`

You need to use it like following :

`cout <<" Height:" <<  size.height<<" Width:"<< size.width<< endl;`

However `frame` is pointer to a `IplImage`

using a `cout` on `frame` will just give you a memory address pointed by `frame`